# Run ember blueprint without a entity name

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I created a ember blueprint that generates the common file structure that we used on all our ember apps however when I run the generator I get the following error because the blueprint is not for a specific entity.

```
ember generate mx-application
version: 1.13.13
installing mx-application
The `ember generate <entity-name>` command requires an entity name to be specified. For more details, use `ember help`.
```

I can get around this by just passing a dummy entity name, however I was wondering if there was a way to ignore the entity name.

```
ember generate mx-application application
```

Answer (score 4):

Try overriding the `normalizeEntityName` function in your blueprints `index.js` to an empty function:

```
normalizeEntityName: function() {}
```

See https://github.com/alphasights/ember-calendar/blob/develop/blueprints/ember-calendar/index.js#L5 for an example :)